# Get Answer Key for TextItems

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms, google-form-quiz

When using google forms in quiz mode, you can create answer keys for multiple choice items and text items.  For multiple choice items in Apps Script's, you can call item.getChoices() and choice.isCorrectAnswer() to identify the correct answer.

Multiple choice: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/multiple-choice-item
Text: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/text-item

**Is there a Google Apps Script function to fetch the correct answer for a TextItem (short answer)**? This can be manually filled in from the UI, but I do not see a way to get or set the value from the script API.

Comment: I looked in the docs and I also don't see a comparable method to .isCorrectAnswer(). I am thinking that you need to use the TextValidationBuilder service and then set the validation on a text item.